# Is the Logitech G502 Hero wheel scroll affected but sunlight hitting it?

Tags: mouse, scrolling, logitech-mouse

I have a Logitech G502 Hero and I noticed that the scrolling does not perform well when the sun is hitting the mouse.

I read that the sensor is a diode. I am not an expert in the field. However, is it possible that the sun blocks the sensor from functioning correctly? If so can someone explain why?

Comment: If black or dark, it could be getting too hot. The sensor is on the bottom, so either it is not the light or the sensor is super sensitive to ambient light.

Comment: @John right thats a good hypothesis also

Comment: The laser sensor that a optical mouse uses isn’t effected by sunlight.  The laser is an entirely different wavelength than sunlight

Comment: @Ramhound even for the scroll wheel?

Comment: @ombk - The scroll wheel is mechanical and unaffected by light

Comment: Who are downvoting all the answers here without leaving comments? Even an answer verified by the poster?

Comment: @harrymc stackoverflow retards... its fine

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe that a large majority of mouse wheels are using an infra red optical sensor.

If you then use the mouse under direct sunlight, the infra red from the
sunlight will interfere with the sensor.

This is in the same sense as not being able to use an IR remote control under
intense direct sunlight.

You may test this by shielding the mouse with your hand while scrolling.

Comment: Indeed this is what i was doing today. I tried shielding the sun and then exposing it to the sun and the performance when exposed to the sun was shit.

Comment: I think that your tests validate my answer as regarding the G502.

Comment: indeed, will wait for more people to interact if possible before confirming the answer

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the scroll wheel uses an optical encoder, which works by shining infrared light from an LED source and receiving it back at the sensor. The light is interrupted by some kind of spokes etc on the scroll wheel, and these interruptions in the light allow it to count how far the scroll wheel has rotated. Unfortunately the sun is also a bright source of infrared and can interfere with that.

I can confirm this also happens with the G604 mouse (why I am searching the topic right now) which uses a similar optical encoder as the G502 in the scroll wheel.

These Logitech mice also have a similar infrared LED sensor on the bottom. Try turning the mouse upside down in the sunlight and you will see the pointer go crazy!

Answer (score -1):

you can find a guide on how to dissasemble it here :

https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Logitech++G502+Hero+Disassembly/140809

.

At step 10 you can see that the wheel sensor is almost 1 piece with wheel, which works with a sensor looking at tiny wheel spokes.

.

I'm not sure 100%, but i'd say you have to check there.

I've same mouse... sunlight would be the last thing i'd check :)

.

Peace